# How to print Chinese letters from R?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, rstudio

I can read Chinese from R and see the Chinese words in RStudio. But I can not figure out how to print out (write) those Chinese words from the R code. 
Here is the example of the code on the console:

```
fi <- 'c:\\R_Routines\\Ch.txt'
g <- readLines(con=fi, encoding='UTF-8')
g
# [1] "发动机测谎报告"
fo <- 'c:\\R_Routines\\Ch1.txt'
fa <- file(fo, encoding='UTF-8')
writeLines(g, con= fa)
fi <- 'c:\\R_Routines\\Ch1.txt'
g <- readLines(con=fi, encoding='UTF-8')
g
# [1] "<U+53D1><U+52A8><U+673A><U+6D4B><U+8C0E><U+62A5><U+544A>"
```

How to output (write on disk) a text file with the Chinese words I read from the file?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but my searching has found several postings suggesting you are not the first person to have trouble with encodings in RStudio. The defaults are accessible with:

[image]

That was a screen shot froma  Windows user. And this is where I found possible location for default settings on a Mac:

[image]

You may also need to use `Sys.setlocale`, but I'd try changing hte RStudio defaults first since it seems as though you were able to initially print the characters.  I'm unable to confirm your problem on a Mac running the R.app GUI or running RStudio on the Mac:

```
> fi <- '~/test.txt'
> g <- readLines(con=fi, encoding='UTF-8')
> g
[1] "发动机测谎报告"
```

The higher values of Unicode are handled with quote-backslash-'u'-numbers-quote. See the help page:

```
?Quotes

'\u53D1'
[1] "发"
```

But trying to replace `"<U+"` with `"\U"` will fail because the R parser will not accept a naked "\U" without succeeding hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Setting locale will not work, because I need to print reports on many languages from the same program. Your example shows that you can read Chinese on Mac. So did I on Windows. My code shows that I perfectly read Chinese text created in some editor and display it  correctly in RStudio. I can not print out (write on disk) the Chinese text to look like  Chinese. R on Windows does not print (writes, exports) the Chinese letters I see in RStudio interface. That is the problem.

Comment: In many cases the issue is the particular font used by a particular application not having glyphs for the particular Unicode character. The default fonts used by R are different on Mac and Windows even when the applications (RStudio?) in use have the same name and general behavior.

Comment: Agree with user3276530. I tried to install the R in my Chinese windows OS.It generated a lot of problem if your system is not English.In some worst cases,the pop-up window will also be displayed as random letter. I recommend you to change the OS to English if it still doesn't work on the new one. It maybe the compatible issue that the R has to fix by its company.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this problem? Did you try `writeLines(...,useBytes=TRUE)` or `writeChar(...,useBytes=TRUE)`?

Comment: Note that I don't think this is a RStudio issue as I discovered this problem while validating a package on http://win-builder.r-project.org/ which I doubt uses RStudio on the backend...